# JS: How would I display a decrementing value through an html header? (and more)

Tags: javascript, html, loops, increment

Basically, I'm making a simple javascript/html webpage game where you guess a number and you have three chances to guess correctly. I'm having a problem displaying the number of attempts a player has left (It gets stuck at three). The color change that is supposed to occur also doesn't happen.

It also doesn't reset the page's display after a refresh (it takes 5 playthroughs of the game to get it to reset).

Maybe my for loop/if statement is screwy?

Here's my code.

```
var guesses = 3;
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
//start the guessing
handleGuess(prompt("Pick a number to win the game!"));

function handleGuess(choice) {
guesses--; //subtract one guess
if (guesses > 0) {
if (choice != random) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#CC0000";
  var x = "";
  x = x + "You have " + guesses + " chances left" + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
} else {
  var x = "";
  x = x + "You win!" + "<br>";

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#009000";
  //return false; 
}
} else {
//running out of turns
var x = "";
x = x + "Game Over!" + "<br>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
//return false;

}
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want it to happen... I can see that, if im not guessing the number right ,it is showing me the prompt box with try again for 3 times after 3 times ,it changing the background to red and shows game over..please be clear on what exactly you want it to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prompt` is a blocking event, so you don't see the page update until after the prompts... try the example below, where [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is used to allow a delay...

```js
var guesses = 3;
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
//start the guessing
handleGuess(prompt("Pick a number to win the game!"));

function handleGuess(choice) {
  guesses--; //subtract one guess
  if (guesses > 0) {
    if (choice != random) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#CC0000";
      var x = "";
      x = x + "You have " + guesses + " chances left" + "<br>";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      setTimeout(function() {
        handleGuess(prompt("Try again!"));
        },1000);//wait 1 second
    } else {
      var x = "";
      x = x + "You win!" + "<br>";

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#009000";
      //return false; 
    }
  } else {
    //running out of turns
    var x = "";
    x = x + "Game Over!" + "<br>";

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    //return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">You have 3 chances to guess the correct number.</h1>

<br>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that the prompt would be what was messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

**Attention.** This is a fully workable example, and definitely an **"overkill demo"** for your "blocking" request.

I've removed the prompt calls with new inputs, and created 2 buttons for the game. One that calls the **Start Game**, and a second for the **"in game try attemps"**.

I'm assuming you are still learning so this example might be helpful for you,by showing the advantages of separating your code into different elements, based on what they are doing, and also making it easier for you to "upgrade" the features of your game.

I could replace a lot more repeated code to make it look better, but that would not make it so familiar anymore to you.

```js
/*function ChangeDif(Difficulty) {
    var i = ""
    if (Difficulty == 'easy'){
        i = 10;
    }
    if (Difficulty == 'medium') {
        i = 5;
    }
    if (Difficulty == 'hard') {
        i = 3;
    }
}
*/
var random = 0;
var start_chances = 3;
var start_attemps = 0;
var x = "";

function startgame() {
  document.getElementById("start").hidden = true;
  document.getElementById("number").hidden = false;
  document.getElementById("again").hidden = false;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pick a number to win the game!";
  random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  //Cheat to see the random number, and make sure the game is working fine
  //document.getElementById("cheater").innerHTML= random;
  max_chances = start_chances;
  step();
}

function lostAchance() {
  max_chances--;
  if (max_chances > 0) {
    step();
  } else {
    loser();
  }
}

function loser() {
  //running out of turns
  x = "Game Over!" + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
  endGame();
}

function step() {
  var choice = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
  if (choice !== random) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#CC0000";
    x = "You have " + max_chances + " chances left" + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("start").hidden = true;
  } else {
    //win
    x = "You win! In " + (start_chances - max_chances) + " attemps <br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#009000";
    endGame();
  }
}

function endGame(){
  document.getElementById("start").hidden = false;
  document.getElementById("again").hidden = true;
  document.getElementById("number").hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" onclick="ChangeDif(this.Difficulty, 'easy')">Easy
  <br>

  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" onclick="ChangeDif(this.Difficulty, 'medium')">Medium
  <br>

  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" onclick="ChangeDif(this.Difficulty, 'hard')">Hard
  <br>
  <h1 id="demo">You have 3 chances to guess the correct number.</h1>
 <input type="number" id="number" hidden />
  <button type="submit" id="start" onclick="startgame()">Let's PLAY</button>
<button type="submit" id="again" hidden onclick="lostAchance()">Try Again</button>
  <p id ="cheater"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely be taking a look at this.